# Import "parselmouth.praat" could not be resolved

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to install [`praat-parselmouth`](https://parselmouth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html) everything is fine when I use Jupyter Notebook.

[image]

But when I tried to import this package on the VsCode I got the below error.

[image]

I've checked the Python interpreter and it's the same as the installed Python directory. How can I solve this?

Comment: You need to like snakes... :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is given in the [link you pasted](https://parselmouth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#importerror-dll-load-failed-on-windows).

Sometimes on Windows, the installation works, but importing Parselmouth fails with an error message saying . This error is cause by some missing system files, but can luckily be solved quite easily by installing the “**Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017**”.

For a 64-bit Python installation: https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/VC_redist.x64.exe

For a 32-bit Python installation: https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/VC_redist.x86.exe

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there is documentation for Windows and I'm working with Apple M1

Comment: I think it would be a better choice to seek solutions from developers in github of this package.